# Migrate folder in /storage/emulated/0/<my_folder> from Android 10 to 11

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-11, android-storage, scoped-storage

In my existing app(Android 10) I have a folder under `/storage/emulated/0/<my_folder>`. After looking to various sources on Google Developers I don't think that it's possible to longer access the `/storage/emulated/0/<my_folder>` directory under Android 11, because of the changes made in [storage access permission](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjyYCUW-9tY).

Of course I can create these folder under Android 11 inside the so called "scoped storage" as mentioned by Google. But if a user updates the app from 10 to 11, **how can I access the old folder for copying the files inside to the new folder inside "scoped storage" when I am on Android 11?**

Or is there some other way to migrate this folder under `/storage/emulated/0/<my_folder>` safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With intent `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` you can let the user choose your `<myfolder>`.

For new installations use `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/<my_folder>` instead.

There is no reason to copy files or folders.

Comment: Thank you, worked for me! [Guide](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/09/example-of-using-intentactionopendocume.html) I used

Answer (score 0):

You can reclaim the permissions for your old app folder via [SimpleStorage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage):

```kotlin
storageHelper.requestStorageAccess(
    expectedStorageType = StorageType.EXTERNAL,
    expectedBasePath = "<my_folder>"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ever since Scoped storage introduction, you can no longer create your folders under root directory without special permission, I.E manage external storage, but i doubt play store will allow that access to your app if the core functionality isnt affected,
You can do one of the following

1. store your required files in respected folders [Recommended] (Documents for docs, DCIM for images/videos, Music for audio files and so on)
2. Require Permission to folder by open document tree intent (Last resort)